# React.js Material-UI: Programmatically hide and show tab

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am trying to show and hide the 2nd tab programmatically yet when I click on the 3rd tab I see the content of the 2nd tab.

Providing my code snippet and sandbox below

Can someone please help?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8je9d

```
export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [Tab2Visible] = useState(false);

  useEffect((newValue) => {
    // const { user } = props;

    console.log("useEffect newValue--->", newValue);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    console.log("newValue--->", newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="simple tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          {Tab2Visible === false ? (
            ""
          ) : (
            <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          )}
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not provide any value property to the `Tab` component, MaterialUI defaults it to the index of the rendered items. Since only two Tab elements are rendered, the handleChange function gives value as 1 for Tab item 3.

Adding an explicit value property will work the way you want it to

```
 <Tabs
       value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="simple tabs example"
    >
      <Tab label="Item One" value={0} {...a11yProps(0)} />
      {Tab2Visible === false ? (
        ""
      ) : (
        <Tab label="Item Two" value={1} {...a11yProps(1)} />
      )}
      <Tab label="Item Three" value={2} {...a11yProps(2)} />
    </Tabs>
```

[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dvm6m?file=/demo.js:1599-2006)

Comment: Thank you Shubham Khatri, much appreciated!

Comment: Shubham Khatri,

I have adjusted the demo with adding a component to tab2 and I am wondering if you might please know how to hide a tab from within a component?

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8je9d